# best method to keep and update unique data entries google app engine python

Tags: google-app-engine

What is the best method to create a database for the given example model and assign each entry with a unique key/name which I already have and to overwrite it if the given key/name shows up again. From what I read you are supposed to use keyname? But I am not getting it to overwrite.

```
class SR(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    url = db.StringProperty()

s = SR(key_name="t5-2rain")
s.name = 't5-2rain'
s.title = 'kaja'
s.url = 'okedoke'
db.put(s)
```

If I enter this again with the same key name but different title value, will create another entry how do I overwrite an existing value with the same key-name.

***Basically how do I populate a table with unique identifiers and overwrite values if the same unique identifier already exist?***
I realize I can search for an existing name or key name etc, call that object make the changes to the instances and repopulate but, I would imagine there has to be a better method than that for overwriting especially if I am trying to put a list where some values may be overwrites and some not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea already.

If 2 `SR` entities were constructed with the same `key_name` argument, then they will have the same `Key` path.  Writing one will overwrite any old `SR` entity which had that `key_name` argument.

You should be able to observe this by querying the datastore for the entity with its unique key:

```
s = db.get(db.Key.from_path('SR', 't5-2rain'))
```

Comment: ok I just called  as you shown and I get the most recent entry for that key name , but I am looking at my development console and I see 3 entries with the same key-name? Why do the old ones still exist? Shouldn't they be overwritten?  Basically if i do as follows I will see 2 entries with same key name in my dev console
s = SR(key_name="t5-2rain")
s.name = 't5-2rain'
s.title = 'kaja'
s.url = 'okedoke'
db.put(s)

s = SR(key_name="t5-2rain")
s.name = 't5-2rain'
s.title = 'kaja2'
s.url = 'okedoke2'
db.put(s)

Comment: Are you seeing this on the dev or production server?  I don't see it in either case (whether using the default db type or sqlite db on the dev server).  Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Weird I removed all entries and then entered it twice and it is now overwriting like it should lol

Comment: Strange indeed.  I'm glad it is working like we'd expect now.